# Java - JTable show only last line from txt file

Tags: java, swing, jtable, text-files

I have txt file like this:

```
User User 1||Address1|telephonecall|X|drivingdepartment|vehicle|X
User User 2||Address2|telephonecall|X|drivingdepartment|vehicle|X
User User 3||Address3|telephonecall|X|drivingdepartment|vehicle|X
User User 4||Address4|telephonecall|X|drivingdepartment|vehicle|X
```

And I tried to show it in JTable like this, but it's only show last line 4 time (as many as how many lines is in text file)

```
    public ArrayList<Voznje> ucitajVoznje() {
        ArrayList<Voznje> zakazaneVoznje = new ArrayList<Voznje>();
        try {
            File voznjeFile = new File("src/txt/voznje");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(voznjeFile));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                String imePrezimeMusterije = split[0];
                String datumPolaska = split[1];
                String adresaPolaska = split[2];
                String nacinPorudzbine = split[3];
                String vozac = split[4];
                String dispecer = split[5];
                String vrstaVozila = split[6];
                String napomena = split[7];

                Voznje novaVoznja = new Voznje(imePrezimeMusterije, datumPolaska, adresaPolaska, nacinPorudzbine, vozac, dispecer, vrstaVozila, napomena);
                zakazaneVoznje.add(novaVoznja);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(zakazaneVoznje);
        return zakazaneVoznje;
    }
 private void initGUI() {
        ArrayList<Voznje> zakazaneVoznje = ucitajVoznje();
        String[] zaglavlje = new String[] {"Musterija", "Datum", "Adresa", "Rezervacija", "Vozac", "Dispecer", "Vrsta vozila", "Napomena"};
        Object[][] prikaz = new Object[zakazaneVoznje.size()][zaglavlje.length];    
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < zakazaneVoznje.size(); i++){
            for (Voznje v : zakazaneVoznje) {
                prikaz[i][0] = v.getImePrezimeMusterije();
                prikaz[i][1] = v.getDatumPolaska();
                prikaz[i][2] = v.getAdresaPolaska();
                prikaz[i][3] = v.getNacinPorudzbine();
                prikaz[i][4] = v.getVozac();
                prikaz[i][5] = v.getDispecer();
                prikaz[i][6] = v.getVrstaVozila();
                prikaz[i][7] = v.getNapomena();

            }
        }

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(prikaz,zaglavlje);
        tblVoznje = new JTable(tableModel);
        tblVoznje.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblVoznje.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblVoznje.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        tblVoznje.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

        JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(tblVoznje);
        add(spSkrol);
        add(tbTulbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Of course, I want to show every single line, but it's looks like this... :
[image]

I suppse that the problem is somewhere with for loop...

Comment: Your nested for loops make no sense. Why are you doing this?

Comment: (1-) Why do you find it so hard to listen to suggestions??? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122350/java-how-to-fill-jtable-from-text-file#comment79252592_46122350 (you also deleted another question giving the same advice), The simple suggestion was to split the row and add the Array to the TableModel using the addRow(...) method. _That is 2 statements inside the loop!!!_

Comment: Now you are splitting the data into an Array. Then you are copying all the data to a custom object. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and take the data from the custom object and add it to a 2D Array. Then you create the DefaultTableModel. The DefaultTableModel will then copy the data from the Array to a Vector of Vectors. You have unnecessary complex code as well as 4 copies of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are filling your data with ALL subjects on every iteration

```
for (int i = 0; i < zakazaneVoznje.size(); i++){
    for (Voznje v : zakazaneVoznje) { // HERE IS THE MISTAKE
        prikaz[i][0] = v.getImePrezimeMusterije();
        prikaz[i][1] = v.getDatumPolaska();
        prikaz[i][2] = v.getAdresaPolaska();
        prikaz[i][3] = v.getNacinPorudzbine();
        prikaz[i][4] = v.getVozac();
        prikaz[i][5] = v.getDispecer();
        prikaz[i][6] = v.getVrstaVozila();
        prikaz[i][7] = v.getNapomena();

    }
}
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < zakazaneVoznje.size(); i++){
    Voznje v=zakazaneVoznje.get(i)
        prikaz[i][0] = v.getImePrezimeMusterije();
        prikaz[i][1] = v.getDatumPolaska();
        prikaz[i][2] = v.getAdresaPolaska();
        prikaz[i][3] = v.getNacinPorudzbine();
        prikaz[i][4] = v.getVozac();
        prikaz[i][5] = v.getDispecer();
        prikaz[i][6] = v.getVrstaVozila();
        prikaz[i][7] = v.getNapomena();
}
```

Comment: Well this may solve the problem, but the real issue is the terrible structure of the code and all the unnecessary looping. I hope the OP takes the time to read my comments.